# I cannot build parity substrate runtimes because the wasm-gc command isn't found

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, webassembly, substrate, parity-io

After following the [compilation instructions](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate#611-linux-and-mac) for my Parity Substrate based node, I repeatedly run into the following issue:

```
./build.sh: line 12: wasm-gc: command not found
```

I cannot build parity substrate runtimes because the wasm-gc command isn't found; what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

There are two potential reasons why you would run into that issue.

#### 1 make sure wasm-gc is installed

To do so, simply use cargo:

```sh
cargo install --git https://github.com/alexcrichton/wasm-gc
```

This will install wasm-gc binary in your `$CARGO_HOME`.

#### 2 make sure cargo binaries are in your `$PATH`

If you are certain the wasm-gc binary is installed correctly, make sure you have the cargo binaries in your `$PATH`, e.g., by setting:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.cargo/bin
```

It's recommended to append this line to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` if you plan on using this more regularly.

Comment: Update October 2019: As of this PR https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/3854 There is no longer a need to manually install `wasm-gc`. It is brought in as a dev- dependency through `Cargo.toml`.